# React Redux can't display an array that is a property of an object. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: react-redux

I'm trying to display an object that's passed as props. One of the object properties is an array. The array is seen in the Redux store, is seen on console.log, is seen in the React tools, but when I try to map over it and display it as a list I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to pass the tickets array as a separate prop but I still get the same error. And all the other properties of `this.props.event` are accessible.

This is my rendering component:

```js
    render(){
        return(

            <div>
                {console.log('New EventDetails props event ', this.props.event)}
                {console.log('New EventDetails props tickets ', this.props.tickets)}


                <h1>Event name: {this.props.event.name}</h1>
                <i>{this.props.event.id}</i>
                <p>Event description: {this.props.event.description}</p>
                <ul><h3>Tickets</h3>
                    {this.props.event.tickets.map(ticket =>{
                        return <Link to={`${this.props.event.id}/tickets/${ticket.id}`}><li key={ticket.id}><p>Price: {ticket.price}</p>
                                   <p>Description: {ticket.description}</p>     
                                </li> </Link>
                    })}

                </ul>

            </div>

        )
    }

}
```

This is the reducer:

```js
import {DISPLAY_EVENT} from '../actions/events'

const eventReducer = (state={}, action) => {
    console.log("single event reducer test, actin.payload: ", action.payload) //shows correct payload

    switch(action.type) {
        case DISPLAY_EVENT:
        return action.payload

        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

I'm passing the props from another component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import EventDetails from './EventDetails'
import {getEvent} from '../actions/events'



class EventDetailsContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Component Did Mount test");
        console.log('EventDetailsContainer props:', this.props);      
        this.props.getEvent(Number(this.props.match.params.id))
      }

      render() {  

        return (
            <div>
                <EventDetails event={this.props.event} tickets={this.props.tickets}/>
            </div>
        )
      }  

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {   
  return {
    event: state.event,
    tickets:state.event.tickets    
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getEvent})(EventDetailsContainer)
```

[This is what I get from the console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNQyU.png).

I expected that the `event.tickets[]` will be accessible just as the other properties but instead it gives this error.

Comment: share the complete react code.. moreover did you connect the mapStateProps method to pass the redux state as props to the component?

Comment: Can you show what you get from the console log of 'New EventDetails props tickets ',)

Comment: I edited the question to include some more code and an image of the console.logs. This is my first question here, so please excuse me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Welcome to SO, avoid posting images, post entire logs.

Comment: @Dennis Vash   I'm sorry, I don't know how to make them look the same as in the browser's console, that's why I opted for a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you console.log `this.props.tickets` but then you map over `this.props.event.tickets`

Comment: Yes, I tried to pass this array as a separate prop, just to test if it will work that way. It doesn't but I have it both as this.props.event.tickets and  this.props.tickets. Originally it was supposed to be event.tickets and that's why I map over that. The effect from trying to map over the this props.tickets is the same

Comment: I see undefined in some previous console.log. If your initialState doesn't have any `event: { tickets: [] }` it might fail before you get the data.. Try to do something like this: `{this.props.event.tickets && this.props.event.tickets.map(ticket =>{...` and you'll see if that helped. It wouldn't render anything on first render and once you have the data, it renders them

Comment: @ jirikolarik Thank you so much! This solved it! You saved my life! This is the answer but I don't know how to mark it as such.

Comment: Glad to help and I hope that your life doesn't really depend on this!:) take care